# Уникальный UUID для уже имеющихся моделей, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.5. Пытаюсь пробежаться по моделям и назначить им UUID скриптом:

```
function unique_guid($model){
        $guid = com_create_guid();
        $table = $model->table;
        $db_table = Db::table($table);
        $req = $db_table->where("guid", strval($guid));
        $request = $req->get();
        $test = $req->count();
        if($req->count()>0){
            $guid = unique_guid($model);
            return;
        }else{
            return $guid;
        }
    }
```

Несколько проходят нормально, но затем обваливается проверка на уникальность? В чём причина? Два часа уже сижу с ним...

*edit
Возможно причина в свойствах колонки UUID в БД, кажется я перестарался в миграции и сделал ->nullable()->unique()

Comment: проверьте что в $model?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/L1EK3XJ

Comment: Что то не так...даже в try/catch зацикливается....проверял в момент сохранения руками - нет такого uuid в БД...

Comment: И отваливается на третьей итерации примерно.. добавляю sleep и побольше работает... wtf....

Comment: Запустите с отладкой и посмотрите в чем дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";');
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE feegleweb_octoshop_products ADD COLUMN guid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() UNIQUE;');
    }
```